# нужно найти наибольший общий делитель в javascript

Tags: javascript

Помогите найти НОД на JS
И есть ли лучший способ решения данного вопроса.

Заранее спасибо за ответы

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: бесконечный цикл, проблема с условием

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код нечитабелен. Оформите его должным образом, пожалуйста.

Снизу универсальное решение для нахождения НОД(Наибольший общий делитель) 2-х и более чисел на `javascript`.

```
function NOD () {
  for (var x = arguments[0], i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var y = arguments[i];
    while (x && y) {
      x > y ? x %= y : y %= x;
    }
    x += y;
  }
  return x;
}

console.log([
  NOD( 10, 15 ),
  NOD( 111, 555, 407 ),
  NOD( 100, 200, 300, 400, 2225, 175, 19873625 ),
].join( '\n' )); 

// Output 5, 37, 25
```

*Если Вам удобнее, то можете посмотреть код на Codepen: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/JwBRGG)*

Answer (score 1):

Да, код трудно понять, поэтому предлагаю вам свою реализацию с помощью рекурсии:

```js
function NOD (x, y) {
 if (y > x) return NOD(y, x);
 if (!y) return x;
 return NOD(y, x % y);
}
console.log(NOD(10, 25));
```